# Don't want list of user which are blocked by user in list?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

```
Table : user 
Id name
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d

Table : block_user
id block_by block
1   1         2
```

when i retrieve list for user 1 at that time i don't want user 2 in list but i stuck at query:
i want user 3 , 4 in place of it return user 2 which is blocked

my sql fiddle [Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9aa0d/2) and my current query

```
Select u.* from user u JOIN block_user bu on bu.block_by = u.Id or bu.block = u.Id where u.Id != 1 GROUP BY u.Id
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also use this is very sort you don'have to join table instead using where not in

```
select * from user where id != 1 and id NOT IN (select block from block_user WHERE block_user.block_by = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `not exists` or `left join`.  The correct logic is:

```
select u.*
from user u
where u.id <> 1 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from block_users bu
                  where bu.block_by = 1 and bu.block = u.id
                 );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer this work for me , sorry but i can't vote up because i don't have reputation. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Use this hope it will help you

```
 select * from user where id = 1 AND id NOT IN 
(select GROUP_CONCAT(block) from block_user where block_by = 1)
```

Comment: this is only return user 1

Comment: thanks for your answer , sorry but i can't vote up because i don't have reputation. thanks again

Answer (score -1):

use can use nesting query with where not in

```
select * from user where id  NOT IN (select block from block_user)
```

Comment: you are providing output for all user but he wants for single user and you are missing group by

Comment: still it is missing group_concat

Comment: this is also retun user 1 only

Comment: thanks for your answer , sorry but i can't vote up because i don't have reputation. thanks again

Comment: i update my answer to get all users list which is not blocked